# Datatables Plugin 'ColumnFiltering()'

Tags: java, jquery

I have this two codes.
Why get i no filtering options with this code below?
I want the regular filtering for each column

```
$(function(){   
oTable = $('#escapeTbale).DataTable().columnFilter({
    "aoColumns": [
                {
                     type: "text",
                     bRegex: true,
                     bSmart: true
                },
                {
                     type: "text",
                     bRegex: true,
                     bSmart: true
                },

                {
                     type: "text",
                     bRegex: true,
                     bSmart: true
                }
             ],

    "sDom": 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',  
    "bJQueryUI":true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,     
 });
```

my HTML Code:

```
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>age</th>            
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

many thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that you have included `'columnFilter.js'` in your html and need to follow table structure with thead and tbody as below to make datatable plugins working

```
<table id="escapeTbale">
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>age</th>            
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>name</td>
        <td>address</td>
        <td>age</td>            
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also check that function name dataTable starts with small d and not caps D. But may be this does not matter much

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
 
    <script src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="TableTools/media/js/TableTools.js"></script>
<script src="TableTools/media/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

That are my includes. Were i get the 'columnFilter.js' ?

Comment: Use below link, copy the contents and save it js folder as jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js                                         https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/source/browse/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js?r=57                                                                 and add below line to import this js file                     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="TableTools/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>

Comment: you are welcome. If this post is useful to you then please accept the answer so that others can refer it as correct answer  :)